# get a string within a string - php

Tags: php, regex, string, numbers

I have a string:

```
[gallery ids="2282,2301,2302,2304,2283,2303,2285,459,1263,469,471,1262,1261,472,608,467,607,606,466,460"]
```

The `ids` will vary, but how can I (in PHP) get the values?

RegExps are not my strong point but I guess we could check for everything within the quotes that comes directly after the word `ids`?

Comment: How about `strpos` + `substr` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a simpler solution, rather than using `preg_match`, is to simply `explode` the string using `"` as the delimiter, where the ids will be the second element (index `1`).

```
$string = '[gallery ids="2282,2301,2302,2304,2283,2303,2285,459,1263,469,471,1262,1261,472,608,467,607,606,466,460"]';

$array = explode('"', $string);

$ids = explode(',', $array[1]);
```

This can be quite elegant from PHP 5.4 where function array dereferencing has been added:

```
$string = '[gallery ids="2282,2301,2302,2304,2283,2303,2285,459,1263,469,471,1262,1261,472,608,467,607,606,466,460"]';

$ids = explode(',', explode('"', $string)[1]);
```

The benefit this has over `preg_match` is that it doesn't matter what the values are -- they could be numbers or letters or other symbols.

Comment: good answer, but preg_match can match anything. It just might be overkill for this simple task.

Comment: True, but you'd need to *know* what the pattern is for the values. With `explode` you don't, so it's more extensible.

Answer (score 5):

Regex: `preg_match_all(/\d+/,$string,$matches);`

Explained demo here: http://regex101.com/r/fE4fE6

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted a non-regex solution, you could do something like this:

```
$str = ...;

$start = strpos($str, '"') + 1; // find opening quotation mark
$end = strpos($str, '"', $start); // find closing   ''     ''

$ids = explode(",", substr($str, $start, $end - $start));
```